# Possible to build blender with latest boost libraries?

Tags: boost, compilation, blender, building

I have a working Blender up-to-date C/C++ build, but it compiles with Boost 1.49.

I would like to use latest Boost libraries (currently 1.53) because of its usage in a related project.

Is it daunting to compile blender with the latest boost?  Has anyone got it working?

Alternatively, is it possible (or recommended) to just leave blender with existing boost 1.49 library and use Boost 1.53 for my small amount of code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have boost 1.52 and blender builds and runs fine.

After installing 1.53 you may need to recompile existing apps to link against the new libs, recent version of programs should be fine with the new libs but some older code may need small adjustments. One change I know of is from code using deprecated versions of boost::filesystem.

To install multiple versions of boost you would want them installed in different locations. This would mean configuring boost with a different PREFIX and you would also need to point your apps to the location of boost libs you want to use with -I in CXXFLAGS and -L in LDFLAGS

Comment: Hi sambler, thanks for that time saving info...  Blender and Boosts are such large beasts that it saves a lot of time to know a large version change is possible.  Would you say the simplest possible way to swap boost while building blender is just to rename the old Boost 1.49 folder in its blender libs/windows/boost folder and replace the boost folder with the latest Boost?

Comment: I would say delete (or uninstall if you installed a pre-built package) the current version and install the new one. Then rebuild any apps that need to be relinked.

Comment: Thanks very much sambler... will do exactly that and will report if I can get latest blender working with latest boost :)